# How to compare dictionary key and queryset value in Django Template

Tags: html, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I'm trying to compare a dictionary key with query set variable in a Django Template. Both output correctly on their own, however, together I cannot compare the values.

```
Django template
{% for object in query_set %}
 {% for key, value in dictionary.items %}
      var key = {{ key }};
      {% if key == query_set.name %}
            <h5> You get this value: {{ value }}</h5>
      {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

What ends up happening is that key gets all the variable values instead of a singular value and it cannot properly compare.

```
Output of key
key var = output 1; key var = output 2; key var = output 3;
```

I think I'm just missing a syntax error or maybe I need to write a custom html tag to do this?

Comment: `if key == object.name` ?

Comment: Nope that does not work. It needs to be {{ key }} to pull the values.